# I want to compare two similar objects structure and list the Difference

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures

I have two complex objects. I want to compare two similar objects structure and list the differences. I have searched in all forums there is no correct Solution.

Everyone is suggesting Reflection method. Reflection method is not helping me I tried it. My object structure is too complex.

The below is my object Structure. The object contain in the list may not be in the same order in other list. one list might have that object, another object might not have that list.

Structure:

object 
       -Field 
      -Field 
      -Field 
     List 
      -Object 
      -object 
      -object 
           -List 
                -object 
                   -Field
                   -Field
           -object
                   -Field
                   -Field
        -Field 
        -Field 
        -List 
               -object 
                   -Field
                   -Field
               -object
               -Field
               -Field

Comment: How about recursively iterating through a layer of your object and counting all Elements of the same classtype. Then comparing it with the layer in your other object

Answer (score 1):

## Reflection API

I still would suggest looking into [Java Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/TOC.html). See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

For example you could make a recursive call with Reflection if an attribute is an object itself and thereby enter it via the same method.

```
public void determineObjectStructure (Object o) {

    Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        // Check Type of field

        // If not primitive -> determineObjectStructure()

        // create Representation
        }
    }
```

Then u can manually create a "complex object structure" representation that contains e.g. a list with:

> levelInComplexObject | object

The final list can then be used for a comparison with such a list created from a different object and their structure can be compared on their different organizational levels.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you for complex objects reflection way of doing becomes bit complex. I also had similar use case where two objects needs to be compared and my object was also very complex (too many different type of fields and chain of associations).

So, did too much search for good way and came across many solutions including reflection way, JSON comparison but  the most promising framework I fond for the Job is [Javers](https://javers.org).

A simple example could be:

```
@Test
public void shouldCompareTwoEntities() {
  //given
  Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
          .withListCompareAlgorithm(LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE)
          .build();

  Employee frodoOld = EmployeeBuilder.Employee("Frodo")
          .withAge(40)
          .withPosition("Townsman")
          .withSalary(10_000)
          .withPrimaryAddress(new Address("Shire"))
          .withSkills("management")
          .withSubordinates(new Employee("Sam"))
          .build();

  Employee frodoNew = EmployeeBuilder.Employee("Frodo")
          .withAge(41)
          .withPosition("Hero")
          .withBoss(new Employee("Gandalf"))
          .withPrimaryAddress(new Address("Mordor"))
          .withSalary(12_000)
          .withSkills("management", "agile coaching")
          .withSubordinates(new Employee("Sméagol"), new Employee("Sam"))
          .build();

  //when
  Diff diff = javers.compare(frodoOld, frodoNew);

  //then
  assertThat(diff.getChanges()).hasSize(9);
}
```

`javers.compare(frodoOld, frodoNew)` takes two objects and compares them and reports the differences. In your case object is having list and elements in the lists could be in different order, in such case `Javers` reports them as difference. If you want order of element should be ignored then before feeding the Objects to the `Javers` you can sort the lists and then compare.

You can have a look at [JaVers Documentation](https://javers.org/documentation/diff-examples/)

Simplest example would be:

```
Person pOld = new Person ();
pOld.setName("Foo"):

Person pNew = new Person ();
pNew.setName("Bar"):

Diff diff = javers.compare(pOld, pNew);
```

`diff.getChanges()` will give list of differences.

Comment: This will be helpful only for when you are creating New Objects. my application is very old. so all are getter and setter objects. i cannot do any code change in my already existing code. without changing my existing code. is there way we can do it?

Comment: @YuvarajSakthivel No, creating objects using builder is there in example is just for test case. Most important line is `javers.compare(frodoOld, frodoNew)` you can directly pass two objects if you have them. No need to change in existing classes.

Comment: I have updated my answer with simple way (getter and setter). You can have a look.

Comment: i have two object, i tried above code. the difference is not showing readable for mat . please check the below output Diff:
1. ValueChange{globalId:'transactionComparator.Employee/', property:'id', oldVal:'4a9e38a5-eb6e-4cdb-9f0b-44cb4f0fd344', newVal:'f361816f-5e97-4139-b45f-1d4e0017937a'}
2. ListChange{globalId:'transactionComparator.Employee/', property:'accidentList', containerChanges:[(0).'transactionComparator.Accident@ba0d7e75'>>'transactionComparator.Accident@fa32bfbb', (1).removed:'transactionComparator.Accident@e946724f', (2).removed:'transactionComparator.Accident@f613f2d9']}

Comment: This is how it reports, what has been changed, what has been added and what has been removed. You need to filter out what you want. It's complete comparison report. If you follow official documents things would be easier.

Comment: but in this result it did not tell which attribute changed. example i have field called accidentName, accidentage. it did not tell anything about primitive level. it tells what changed. it did not tell what value changed. please add some code hre

Comment: It will tell all differences if class has `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods.

Comment: No, it is not telling what values changed. it just telling only ListChanges and container Changes. actually am expecting under the list under this object , this primitive value changed from this to this.

Answer (score 0):

## ANTLR

The [*ANTLR* project](http://www.antlr.org/) is a set of sophisticated tools for analyzing source code. See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).

You author a grammar that defines the rules of a programming language. For Java, that has already been done. You can download open-source grammar `.g4` file for Java language.

You feed this grammar into ANTLR. Out comes source code for a lexer to recognize the words of a source code file, and a parser to recognize the phrases and statements of a source code file.

You compile these generated source files. Then feed your Java source files. Out comes an Abstract Syntax Tree, a data structure representing your Java source code content. You can walk that tree easily, collecting parts (class name, member variables, methods, arguments, local variables, etc.) as you go.

Walking the tree is made easy by using more source code generated by ANTLR. This code uses the Listener and the Visitor patterns so you can override just the few methods for the parts in which you are interested.

ANTLR is open-source and free-of-cost.

See the excellent guide and reference book written by the principal creator of ANTLR, [Terence Parr](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Parr), titled [*The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference*](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference).